# double subscript error $}

Tags: matrices

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to fit this large matrix equation into the page margins, but I keep getting double subscript error, any suggestions are welcome, tnx!

Here is the code:

```
\begin{equation}\\
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!} 
{$
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{A} \\
V_{B} \\
V_{C} \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_A+X_{AA} & X_{AB} & X_{AC} & X_{AN_1} & X_{AN_2} & R_{AG}+X_{AG} \\
X_{BA} & R_B+X_{BB} & X_{BC} & X_{BN_1}& X_{BN_2} & R_{BG}+X_{BG} \\
X_{CA} & X_{CB} & R_C+X_{CC} & X_{CN_1}  & X_{CN_2} & R_{CG}+X_{CG} \\
X_{N_1A} & X_{N_1B} & X_{N_1C} & R_N_1 +X_{N_1N_1} & X_{N_1N_2} & R_{N_1G}+X_{N_1G} \\
X_{N_2A} & X_{N_2B} & X_{N_2C} & X_{N_2N_1} & R_{N_2}+X_{N_2N_2} & R{N_2G}+ X_{N_2G} \\
* &* &* &* &* &*\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{A} \\
I_{B} \\
I_{C} \\
I_{N_1} \\
I_{N_2}\\
I_G\\
\end{bmatrix}
$}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: please always post code as text that can be tested, not as an image.

Comment: You have `R_N_1` which should be `R_{N_1}`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing `R_N_1` to `R_{N_1}`, you should also change `R{N_2G}` to `R_{N_2G}`.

A separate issue: Instead of using `\resizebox` to shoehorn the equation into the available space, consider employing a `\small` directive *outside* the `equation` environment. If you really want to use `\resizebox`, you should use `0.94\textwidth` as the design width, *not* `1\textwidth`. Why? Because you need to set aside some space to typeset the equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begingroup % localize scope of the "\small" directive
\small
\begin{equation}
   \setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
    \begin{bmatrix}
    V_{A} \\
    V_{B} \\
    V_{C} \\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    R_A+X_{AA} & X_{AB} & X_{AC} & X_{AN_1} & X_{AN_2} & R_{AG}+X_{AG} \\
    X_{BA} & R_B+X_{BB} & X_{BC} & X_{BN_1}& X_{BN_2} & R_{BG}+X_{BG} \\
    X_{CA} & X_{CB} & R_C+X_{CC} & X_{CN_1}  & X_{CN_2} & R_{CG}+X_{CG} \\
    X_{N_1A} & X_{N_1B} & X_{N_1C} & R_{N_1} +X_{N_1N_1} & X_{N_1N_2} & R_{N_1G}+X_{N_1G} \\
    X_{N_2A} & X_{N_2B} & X_{N_2C} & X_{N_2N_1} & R_{N_2}+X_{N_2N_2} & R{N_2G}+ X_{N_2G} \\
    * &* &* &* &* &*
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    I_{A}   \\
    I_{B}   \\
    I_{C}   \\
    I_{N_1} \\
    I_{N_2} \\
    I_G 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```